# How to find the character which is throwing UnicodeDecodeError when reading any file with 'utf-8' encoding

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8

When reading a file from pandas read_csv , got UnicodeDecodeError.
Syntax:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file_name.csv", sep='|')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

How do I get which charcter is throwing the error at which location in file.

Comment: The error means that the file is *NOT* UTF-8 encoded. You need to find the correct encoding and pass it through the `encoding` parameter

Comment: Most likely the encoding matches the locale of the end user's machine. You can get it with `sys.getdefaultencoding()`. To avoid such issues and guessing though, you should ensure the CSV files are saved as UTF8

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sometimes you don't have any control over how CSV files are saved, because they're not written by a program under your control.

Comment: @MarkRansom you do actually. Because if any program still saves in the system locale it has a critical, 20+ year old bug. It may not appear that way to people in the US, but to the rest of the world Unicode is a necessity, used since the Windows NT line made Unicode the native system encoding. Since 2000 one has to work extra hard to introduce encoding problems in Windows. Unfortunately, some will do so instead of acknowledging they have a bug until they can somehow cover the "fix" as a new version

Comment: @MarkRansom I remember a Greek accounting software firm managed to create an ASCII only accounting program with *.NET* (also natively Unicode, same as Java etc) - they used `varchar` instead of `nvarchar` in the database. For almost 10 years all local MVPs would pester them to fix the bug but nooooo,it was M$ and SQL Server's fault. They were able to keep up the charade until ... commerce from Slavic countries picked up, and their competitor's software worked just fine without conversion errors, while their own couldn't handle both Greek and Slavic text

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can't argue the sensibility of using UTF-8 everywhere.  But people use software with 20+ year old bugs every day.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I had the same doubt that file is not utf-8 when error popped up. But using 'chardet' library, I verified its encoding. The file is utf-8 encoded but some characters are not due to which the error is thrown.

Comment: @Surendra that proves it's **not UTF8**. **All** single-byte codepages **and** UTF8 have the same bytes in the range 0-127 (0x00-0x7f). If you have only English text there's **no way** to tell what codepage was used to create it. In UTF8 characters beyond the first 127 are encoded using two or more bytes and `0xA0` is simply invalid. This means *you still don't know the encoding*. The page you're just reading is UTF8. Click `View Source` and check it - no strange escape sequences. Use a hex editor - no strange bytes. And no `0xa0`.

Comment: @MarkRansom not in this case. It's like saying you haven't noticed your work PC or POS crashes every 5 minutes. For the last 20 years. Or you didn't notice you're still using DOS instead of Windows. *Outside the US*, it's simply not possible to work without Unicode, except in very limited circumstances - all company, partner, customer machines must be using the same locale, which typically means they must be in the same country. Which may have been the case with **Linux server machines** until recently, but definitely not with user machines for the last 20+ years

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos most of the library determines the encoding by reading first few bytes of the file. If at any location by chance any unwanted character is present it doesn't flag that the file cannot be created. Try Creating a dummy file in notepad with some unwanted character after few bytes and read it.

Comment: @Surendra again, and again, this proves this file doesn't use the UTF8 encoding. For English text, UTF8, Latin1, Cyrillic or *any* other single-byte codepage result in *the same bytes*. Your file uses *another* codepage. `0xA0` is valid in most single-byte codepages. It's *not* valid in any way in UTF8.

Comment: @Surendra the short version is - you don't have UTF8. You can probably read that file by specifying any other codepage, eg `latin1`, and may get no error, garbled non-English text, or a conversion error. You have to use the *correct* codepage to read the file without problems. Or fix the software that produces the file to use UTF8

Answer (score 1):

If the whole file is small enough to read into memory, you can read it in binary mode and decode it yourself.  The error message will then tell you the exact byte offset.

```
with open("file_name.csv", "rb") as f:
    f.read().decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Doesn't the error already specify the character *and* the position? Besides, this won't help fix the problem - this isn't a UTF8 file.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the position given by Pandas will vary by how it's reading the file; it's not relative to the beginning of the file.  And step one of finding the correct encoding is finding out what character is supposed to be there, which requires some context before and after the bad byte.

Comment: @MarkRansom Agree with the point that position is not relative to beginning of the file.

Comment: @MarkRansom File is >500MB,  so is there any other way to find the position or line number which is causing the problem from beginning of file.

Comment: @SurendraKumar you can open the file in text mode with the `utf-8` encoding, then read it line by line and increment a counter for each line.  Use try/except to catch the line where it fails and print the counter.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yeah reading line by line is useful. I was able to leverage pandas read_csv parameter 'nrows' and by hit-and-trial method was able to locate the exact line number.

Answer (score -1):

read_csv takes an encoding option to deal with files in different formats.You will not get error if you include the unicode decode

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file_name.csv", sep='|',encoding = "utf-8")
```

Alternatively you can also use

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', engine='python')
```

Comment: The error message already indicates it's bombing on a UTF-8 conversion. I don't see how this will help.